# Is it possible for a character to attain a Strength Ability Score of 30?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores

[The table](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/usingAbilityScores.htm) mapping an ability score to a modifier covers Ability Scores from 1 to 30.

[A previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144591/1355) established that it is indeed possible to attain an Ability Score of 1 due to effects lowering a character score below its nominal value.

This question wishes to explore the other end of the spectrum:

**Is it possible for a character to attain a Strength Score of 30?**

---

*[Another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119438/1355) established that 30 is the absolute cap: there is no way to go over 30. It is mentioned that monsters and gods could have an Ability Score of 30, but not that a character could.*

Comment: @Rubiksmoose: I could not find any evidence that a character can indeed attain a Strength Score of 30 in the linked question/answers, only that it could not exceed 30, did I miss something?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Try seeing if [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122965/what-is-the-highest-ability-score-possible?noredirect=1&lq=1) answers that better. Are you just looking for what a score theoretically can be or for how it can be achieved?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose: Thanks, the latter is just spot on! I had not noticed that Manuals could be stacked, or that an Epic Boon existed. (I was looking for how to achieve it, I'd like a +10 modifier if possible!)

Comment: @Bloodcinder: I have tried to clarify the question without a "pseudo-answer" in the body of the question.

Comment: @MatthieuM. you might be able to carve a non-duplicate question out of "How can I achieve a 30 strength" actually. considering that second link was closed it means those answers may not represent the best or all available options to do so. However, you are going to have to edit in your exact restrictions on what you are looking for to make it a viable question. For example, does it need to be permanent? Do magic items count? etc.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose: [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/122967/1355) is exactly what I was looking for, so I'm content with my question remaining closed. Note that "duplicates" never get removed, they act as redirection signs, so the linked question will not go anywhere anytime soon :)