# What is the maximum number of spells a character can have?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic

What is the largest amount of spells one character can have at one time?

This includes Multiclassing, feats, Background, and Races.

The character does not have to be functional in any way. It just has to have as many spells as possible.

Comment: Do you mean spells known/available, or spells prepared/ready to cast?

Comment: Would you also include spells that can only be cast as rituals? Or spells that can only be cast via a magical item? And are you concerned with number of spells that a character knows, or number they could cast in one day? (E.G. Does it matter if they know 100 spells but have only one spell slot?)

Comment: Maximum number of spells cast in a day?

Comment: @Iter please do not put answers in the comments. The comments are only for asking for  clarifications or suggesting improvement. To place an answer you will have to wait for OP to help clarify the question and then place it in the proper place when/if the question is reopened. Answers in comments will get deleted. See [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) for our policy.

Comment: what level is this character?

Comment: Related: [Most prepared spells at level 20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/135224/48759)

Comment: What's your intended use for this?