# What class has the most spells known or prepared (aside from Wizard)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

As I feel like this needs to be asked, I have noticed that all spellcasting classes really get a limited amount of spells at a time, such as spells known or spells prepared. I have to ask, though, which class can prepare the most spells? I'm currently on the side of the Cleric, though I could be wrong.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to increase the maximum number of spells a level 20 wizard, druid or cleric can prepare?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/135224)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Clerics seem to win

The classes that prepare their spell lists (Cleric, Druid, Wizard) all prepare a number equal to class level + spellcasting ability modifier (Paladins get half their level), ie. 25 at Level 20 (assuming a spellcasting ability score of 20). In addition Clerics get domain spells (total of 10 by 9th level, which are always prepared), land  and spore druids get 8 domain spells (by 9th level). Wizards only get to prepare two additionals, and that at Level 20. Artificer is a "half-caster" so prepares only 15 spells at 20th level, but gets 10 spells from their specialisation, for a total of 25.

Of the classes that don't prepare spells, Bard has the most with 22 (+2 for College of Lore), Warlock gets 15 (+4 for mystic arcanum and up to 8 more via Invocations for a potential 27. Ty C. Martin), Sorcerers get a flat 15, and Rangers 11. Both Arcane Trickster and Eldritch Knight get 13 by level 20. (All these numbers for Level 20).

There may be some levels and ability score combinations where other classes have more spells, but for purely classes Clerics come out as the winners (35 at level 20 with a Wisdom of 20).

Comment: Would it be possible to know/prepare more spells by multiclassing, even if they were all low-level spells?

Comment: Also worth noting: [Wizards](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#Spellcasting) can cast any ritual in their spellbook, whether or not that spell is prepared. So in theory, a wizard could have the most spells available throughout an adventuring day, even though they don't have the most prepared.

Comment: @V2Blast yes, but that feels like the answer to a different question: "How can a character have the most spells prepared?"

Comment: Wait, so the Mystic Arcanums DOESN'T count against your number of known spells?

Comment: @SlayerTheKid MA spells aren't technically known, you just choose a spell (of a set level) and can cast it once per LR. Warlock spells known must be of a level they have spell slots and MA levels are above spell slots. Warlocks are weird, OK.

Comment: If we go into the subclasses and think about races, I think the Human Variant Arcana Cleric wins it hands down.

He also gets additional spells at some levels and if you add an ritual casting feat and so on into it..