# I need help calculating min/max damage possible with this character

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, damage, attack-roll, player-vs-player

I'm posting a link to the character's sheet because I'm not even sure I got all the attack options and damage additions I have or what order they need to go in to get the maximum possible damage out of the character below. I just need to know know what the best attack order is and how much the minimum/average/maximum damage will be for the very first round when I have won the initiative roll to have advantage from attack an enemy that has not taken a turn in combat yet. Then what the subsequent rounds of damage would look like after using all the one-time use options have been used such as spell slots and daily reset abilities.

This build is not for legal play or for play in campaign. It is a character that is being built for a PvP tournament that players are putting on at a local game store. There are 30 people so far who signed up. The edits to the weapons showing the added potion of giant was just a way for me to try and keep track of all the added damage needed in my failed attempt to try and get the answers I'm looking for.

The parameters are that:

1. any class, Item, Race, Background, Subclass, and spells that are available options on DnD beyonds character creator with all the Sources, Partnered content, and optional feats from every available book they have.
2. You can have a total of 15 feats from all sources (but all the feats that do the same things just worded different like two-weapon fighting count as one so you get all the benefits from what the skill should be able to do).
3. You get all the expert skill feats you want to take.
4. You can be attuned to only 6 items maximum.
5. No limit on the amount of magic items you can have that do not require attunement.
6. Ay weapon you choose can be made into a +3 weapon if it is not already one.
7. You can use a maximum of 25 tomes that Raise your Attributes.
8. You can take any potion and apply any poison or activate any item that requires an action or bonus action to activate, before rolling for initiative, but can not cast any spells or abilities or start the match invisible.
9. You have to roll for starting stats (3 sets rolling a d20 6 times re-rolling any 1-9 rolls keeping only 10-20’s rolls).
10. Have to take average health.
11. Combat and gameplay rules from official sources will be used for play.

The things not allowed are:

1. No **personally** created Races, Feats, subclasss, Items, Spells, or rules are allowed.
2. no wish spells, unlimited summons, infinite loop, or builds that create multiple copies of yourself or a summon.
3. no greater invisibility Spells, Items, or Potions.
4. No spell scrolls before or during the match.
5. No Epic boons.

It will be one one-on-one to-the-death elimination style play. Drawing from a hat to determine the matchups. In a different custom arena for each Elimination round of play, so you never play in the same arena twice.

I think I have a good build to do a pretty decent job in the tournament with a good chance for massive damage but also a good bit of ability to mitigate and handle damage.

[Link to PDF of Character Sheet](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sheet-pdfs/solodragon13_120878139.pdf)

[Link to DnD Beyond character Sheet if You Don't Want to Download the PDF Version](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/120878139/PCf8ii)

I have chosen
High Elf, Fighter champion 5, Ranger gloom stalker 3, and Rouge Assassin 12

Stats- Str 30, Dex 30, Con 30, Int 10,  Wis 30, Cha 10, Proficiency 7.

Feats- Elven accuracy, Piercer, Metamagic Adept (quickened spell & empowered spell), Poisoner (for the poison resistance ignore since we can apply and drink potions out of combat prior to the match starting except for greater invisibility), Dual wielder, Two weapon fighting style, Twin weapon fighting master, Twin wielder, Duel expertise, Attunement master, K.i.s.s Master, Martial Adept (Menacing Attack, Precision Attack), Explosive Crit, Savage attacker, Squire of Solamnia (background feat),

Items- Blood Fury Tattoo, Ioun Stone of Mastery, Red Wizard Blade +3 (Oil of Sharpness) Bloodshed Rapier +3 (oil of sharpness).

Potions & poisons- Purple Worm Poison (Both Weapons), Potion of Heroism, Potion of Giant Size, Potion of Speed.

Spells- Booming Blade, Gilver's Wind Blade Roulette (1d10+10 to six targets) or (6d10+[60 or 10 I'm not sure how the +damage works when it only targets one enemy instead of 6] to 1 target, 1 action, 1 spell slot level 1), Hunters Mark.

Comment: Welcome to the stack SoloDragon13!  Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you have a moment, and feel free to peruse the [help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) center for more in-depth info about the site.

Comment: If this character is legal, there is a lot of homebrew going on. We don't know what options are available to you if we don't know these homebrew rules. If there aren't any homebrew rules, this character isn't legal.

Comment: @SoloDragon13, that is quite a character.  Why did you just take 30s in four attributes?  Why not all six?

Comment: I don't think the character is legal in any situation anywhere.  Not in any actual playable scenario.  But if it is, there's room to grow.  There seems to be no limit on feats.  Why not take them all?

Comment: The Statline is clearly not legal: **30** is not a legal value for statistics.

Comment: Why 20 is the limit for a statine and some rarely achieve a little more, read [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/192862/30306)

Comment: @Trish 30 is possible with multiple Manual of Bodily Health for con and the respective items for other attributes.

Comment: @JoakimM.H. you can not use more than one of the same item and benefit from it.

Comment: 30 is legal if it's a homebrew challenge and the challenge rules say something like, "use 140 points across your attributes, none to exceed 30".  There are clearly rules going on here that we don't understand.

Comment: @SoloDragon13 That is an improvement.  Can you please also actually incude a **single** question in your text?  As written, your title reads sort of like, "tell me what to do", which is too broad.

Comment: @Trish ALTERNATIVES TO EPIC BOONS
You might decide to grant one of the following rewards to a 20th-level character, instead of awarding an epic boon. These two options can be awarded to a character more than once.
Ability Score Improvement. The character can increase one ability score by 2 or increase two ability scores by 1 each. The ability score can now be increased above 20, up to a maximum of 30.
New Feat. The character gains a new feat chosen by the player, but subject to your approval. https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/other-rewards

Comment: @SoloDragon13 What level is this supposed to be then?! That is by far not a normal campaign legal character, where the attribute cap is normally 20! There is so much missing, that the question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Trish and it is easy to get your strength score in perfectly legal and official WotC play guides with the belt of giant strength raising strength to 29 and many other items raise the cap to 22 and 24 in other scores. All the parameters are listed in the question as well as the things not allowed. The character follows all the rules allowed in the tournament. Only thing I'm asking for is someone to do the math for the minimum and maximum possible damage this character is capable of. It's pretty simple question for someone who is good with the math and rules involved with damage

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your question is directly answerable.  We don't know the parameters of your challenge, and that character's kinda complicated.  Rather than vote to close, I'm going to try to answer your question more broadly.

You should also understand that character breaks sooo many rules.  There's nothing wrong with that, people make homebrew games all the time that break the rules, but it **does** make it pretty difficult for strangers on the internet to provide much help.

As an example, about Attributes, the Basic Rules say (emphasis added):

> A score of 10 or 11 is the normal human average, but adventurers and many monsters are a cut above average in most abilities. A score of 18 is the highest that a person usually reaches. **Adventurers can have scores as high as 20**, and monsters and divine beings can have scores as high as 30.

And, of course, your character has four 30s.

#### Seek help from the DM, or other players

You say:

> I am very new to dnd

The character you present is completely over the top.  There's nothing wrong with that, but at first reading it's hard to believe that you've understood the parameters of the challenge.

#### That is a massively complicated character, it needs review

As a tiny example, there seems to be the description of a potion of giant size in the notes of your bloodshield rapier.

As another example, why not 30 in intelligence and charisma as well?

#### Review the rules, in detail

If you're engaging in a 20th level PvP tournament, you need to understand the rules, completely.  At a guess, most of the people you'll be playing with will be.

#### Practice

If there's someone you can practice with ahead of time, that might help.  Just two of you can walk it through.

#### Consider a different option

The challenge you're referring to compares to D&D the way playing chess with, oh, 5 extra queens compares to regular chess.  Or playing poker with two decks mixed together.

There's *nothing wrong with that*.  Play D&D however you want to play, but you should understand that is a **very** specialized form of D&D, and bears as much resemblance to "real D&D" as the chess and poker I mentioned compares to the "real" rules for those games.

Maybe the game store has some options for new players.  My best recommendation is to start playing D&D with simple level 1 characters and a simple adventure.  Maybe that sounds boring compared to a 20th level PvP tournament, but really it isn't.  It's a great game, and it's worth learning from the beginning.

Comment: The official DM guide also says this about ability scores ALTERNATIVES TO EPIC BOONS
You might decide to grant one of the following rewards to a 20th-level character, instead of awarding an epic boon. These two options can be awarded to a character more than once.
Ability Score Improvement. The character can increase one ability score by 2 or increase two ability scores by 1 each. The ability score can now be increased above 20, up to a maximum of 30.
New Feat. The character gains a new feat chosen by the player, but subject to your approval.

Comment: This character is meant to play against other Player characters following the same set of parameters. It's not for campaign play or play against NPC or monsters. It is simply the same exact type of one-shot play as any other PvP tournament such as the ones they run on critical role. Just instead of a battle royal style match it is one-on-one style play with more powerful characters and options to make the combat go faster and more exciting.

Comment: @SoloDragon13 The rules you edited into your question say "No epic boons".  If I were the DM, I would also outlaw "Alternatives to Epic Boons", because . . . an alternative to an epic boon is an epic boon.  I advise you to take the advice in my answer, and talk to the DM and other players.  Also, I advise you to take my advice and focus your question to a **single** question.  It's too broad, and it's about to be closed.

Comment: Plus raising an ability score to 29-30 is not something that WotC does not already contribute to. The item belt of giant strength will raise your max strength to 29 add on a tome that increases strength and you easily have 30 strength 31 actually but 30 is the officially recommend max hard cap to ability scores. So it's not like it is so out of the box or unheard of.

Comment: To broad it's one question with two parts. How much damage is this character capable of doing in one round attacking first on an enemy who has not taken a turn yet. And what does that attack sequence look like? What is so hard to answer about that if you are good at the math and rules regarding attack damage?

Comment: And alternatives to epic boons are not epic boons they are alternatives to them. Everyone involved in the tournament know the parameters and they had a meeting with the organizers and first players to sign up to agree and discuss what was accepted and what to leave out. This is something that everyone involved with it is in agreement on how it will be played.

Comment: Also of course it is a complicated character that's why I'm asking for a more experienced player who is into theory crafting and min/maxing characters to look at it and give me a rundown on the damage it is capable of. It's not a hard question to answer for someone who deals with the math easily. There are many post of people posting theoretical builds with attack breakdowns trying to get the highest single-round damage possible so you tell me exactly what makes this question unanswerable apart from your personal opinion that this is not how the game should be played?

Comment: @SoloDragon13 Your character has homebrewed magic items, so those are presumably allowed if this character is legal for your tournament. The highest damage you could do is to use the Longbow of Sudden Doom which has a +infinity bonus to hit and +infinity bonus to damage.

Comment: No, it doesn't in my question I clearly stated that I added those notes about the potion to the weapons just to try and keep track of all the damage that I needed to add to an attack. It is not a homebrew item at all all the items and gear is found in the inventory list listed on DnD Beyond. None of it is made up or homebrew.

Comment: "Arm Shield right", "Arm shield Left", "Demon Armor of Black Swordsman", "Bad Lantern" at least all appear to be homebrew.  Falling (further) down this rabbit hole I can't help but notice that none of the other characters in the campaign your character is a part of have scores over 20.  Not saying that's wrong, you know better than we do.  I am saying, again, you might want to check in with the DM on some of these things.