# Wood elf initiative

Tags: dnd-5e, initiative, elf

I am playing a Wood Elf Monk. I have a 20 dex, so my initiative is +5. Do wood elves gain any other pluses to initiative?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 10):

## No, wood elves gain no special bonus to initiative

You don't get additional bonuses to initiative unless you have a feature (racial trait, class feature, feat, spell, magic item, etc.) which says so. Or specifically, gives a bonus to

- Initiative rolls (like the Alert feat)
- Generic Dexterity ability checks (like the Champions Remarkable athlete feature)
- Generic ability checks (like the Bard's Jack of all Traits feature)

For how to boost your initiative into the skies, see: [How high can a PC's initiative bonus get?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136696/52137)

Answer (score 1):

## Wood Elves do not get any special bonuses to initiative

As can be seen under the relevant [races section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/races#Elf) in DnDBeyond, wood elves do not get any bonuses to initiative bar the +2 in their Dexterity scores that all elves get.