# Which magical items impose disadvantage on attacking creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, advantage-and-disadvantage

I am currently trying to optimize my level 20 Barbarian character. I am aiming to be a tank, and to maximally penalize enemies for attacking other members of my party over myself.

So far, I have:

- Adopted the Bear Totem, which:

  - Imposes disadvantage on enemies who choose to attack my allies instead of me when I am within 5ft of them.
  - Gives me resistance to all damage types (except psychic).
- Taken the Sentinel feat, which allows me to use a reaction to attack an enemy within 5ft of me who chooses to attack my ally over me.
- Taken Shield Master, which lets me avoid all damage on successful Dex saves.
- My equipment has given me an AC of 29 ([this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/88396/15689) is superb on the topic of AC).

At the end of our last session our DM told us that we are permitted to acquire 2 magical items of our choosing for free (thanks to defeating a large, god-like boss).

This got me thinking if there are any magical items which would impose disadvantage on enemies attacking me, since this would be in line with what I have already done with my character, while also helping to penalize enemies who, given my character design above, will likely be attacking me.

The only item I've been able to find is a Cloak of Displacement, which:

> ...projects an Illusion that makes you appear to be standing in a place near your actual location, causing any creature to have disadvantage on Attack rolls against you. If you take damage, the property ceases to function until the start of your next turn. This property is suppressed while you are Incapacitated, Restrained, or otherwise unable to move.

While this is certainly an option, I am curious if there are any other better magical items which would impose disadvantage on enemy attack rolls. We are permitted to take any magical items (except UA), and since there are so many, I figure there must be rarer items I could use that may come with additional benefits beyond just imposing disadvantage, or maybe come without the downsides of a Cloak of Displacement.

**So which magical items impose disadvantage on enemy attack rolls?**

If the Cloak of Displacement is the only item then I am happy to accept an answer verifying this is the case.

I am also open to other magical item suggestions, though these suggestions may be beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I searched through the DMG and looked at every use of the word "disadvantage". I am reasonably certain this list is comprehensive, at least for material in the DMG.

- *Boots of Speed*: Opportunity attacks have disadvantage on any round the speed increase is active. It takes a bonus action to activate, and lasts for up to 10 minutes between long rests.
- *Cloak of Displacement*: Confers disadvantage on all attacks against you until somebody manages to land a blow, as long as you are not incapacitated, restrained, or prevented from moving. If lost to damage, the protection returns on your next turn.
- *Ring of Elemental Command*: Confers disadvantage on all attacks by elementals from the related plane.
- *Robe of Scintillating Colors*: Spend one of three charges, and among other benefits, all attacks against you have disadvantage until the start of your next turn.
- *Saddle of the Cavalier*: All attacks against your *mount* have disadvantage.
- *Spellguard Shield*: All spell attacks have disadvantage against you.

Comment: Accepted since you explained your method

Answer (score 5):

Cloak as you mentioned.

Boots of Speed:
When activated double your movement speed and provide disadvantage on attacks of opportunity against you.

Robe of Scintillating Colors:
Creatures that can see you have disadvantage on attack rolls against you. Requires charge expenditure.

The Spellguard shield: Provides disadvantage to spell attack rolls against you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if this list is extensive?

Comment: I think you mean exhaustive...

Answer (score 3):

***Boots of Speed***:

> any creature that makes an opportunity attack against you has disadvantage on the attack roll.

***Robe of Scintillating Colors***:

> [Until the end of your next turn after you spend a charge] Creatures that can see you have disadvantage on attack rolls against you.