# Is there any way to increase your proficiency bonus other than leveling up?

Tags: dnd-5e, proficiency

Last Friday, I played my first session of D&D and I loved it.

I have a little bit of an obsession with seeing how to make characters be specifically optimised in one area. Right now I'm trying to figure out what is the highest usable base AC of a playable race.

So far I've come to the warforged race with their heavy armor for Integrated Protection. You have to be proficient with heavy armor, but from what I can tell, that has the possibility of giving the highest usable AC.

Class doesn't seem to matter, as long as you get proficiency with heavy armor.

But back to the race. With the warforged's Integrated Protection, the plate armor gives you an AC of 16 + proficiency bonus. At level 16, that would make your AC equal to 16 + 6, for a total of 22.

**With that in mind, is there any way of increasing your proficiency bonus other than level?**

Comment: Just for kicks, you should know that 22 is nowhere near [5e's highest AC](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67197/23970). *[not responsible from any drama caused by playing builds at that link]*

Comment: Yeah, I was sure there was a way to get it higher, but one thing i failed to specify in the post was I'm trying to find the highest sustainable AC without magic items and spells. Just racial traits, shields or other armor, class buffs, and feats. But thank you for the link, I'd be happy to take a look at it!

Comment: @Aaronthekil could you please update the question with your comment? Since the first answer is a magic item and I'm certain a lot of people (myself included) would first go looking for a magic item to assist you.

Answer (score 11):

At the time of writing, the only officially published material by WotC which can increase your proficiency bonus is the [Ioun Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ioun-stone) of Mastery.

> **Mastery (Legendary).** Your proficiency bonus increases by 1 while this pale green prism orbits your head.